# How to write a Python script to search for a keyword in a particular website's database using the website's search bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to search for a keyword in a particular website using its search bar. For example I want to search about "birds" in Wikipedia. For that I have to open Google Chrome, then open Wikipedia, then search for the word "birds" in Wikipidea's search engine.

I want to automate this process using Python. I'm using PyCharm.

Comment: `For [that] I have to open google chrome,then open [wikipedia, ]then search for the word "birds" in…` No. (Well, a GUI user might have to - a script doesn't.)

Comment: I'm not going to provide an answer but, you need to look for the following keywords. Beautiful-Soup, python requests, python selenium modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If emulating a browser user activity is OK to you, you may consider installing Selenium and Chrome webdriver (here is the instruction: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/ ).
"Example 1" is similar to the solution of your problem.

The search bar is `<input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" title="Search Wikipedia [alt-shift-f]" accesskey="f" id="searchInput" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">` element and has "searchInput" id, which you can use to select it with `el = browser.find_element_by_id("searchInput")`
Then use `el.send_keys('birds' + Keys.RETURN)` to fill the input with your request and search.

So the script may look like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page')

print("Enter a keyword to search on wikipedia: ", end='')
keyword = input()

elem = browser.find_element_by_id('searchInput')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys(keyword + Keys.RETURN)

# do something with the opened page

browser.quit()
```

If you don't want to emaluate browser activity, you may resolve it somehow with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup4` modules, but the solution will be more complex, though, probably, more efficient

Comment: @Hawkingo, I've edited my answer and added taking a keyword from user. Is it what you wanted me to do?

Comment: Is if possible to do that on Github? Give keyword and let the searh. I tried smt similar to your code but did not work.

Comment: @anonymouss, I would better use `requests` + `bs4` for this, so [here is an example](https://gist.github.com/Hofsiedge/a79551dd0f8ca9908fd932222fbcbc9b) showing how to fetch repo descriptions from the search page.

Comment: @anonymouss, also, using `requests` + `bs4` it's possible to fetch the data asynchronously (fetching multiple requests simultaneously in a single thread), drastically increasing performance. If you need an example of that (or the option with `selenium`), I can provide you with it as well

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try your suggestion with requests + bs4 but I also want to see the selenium option if it is possible. Thnx again ;)

Comment: @anonymouss, alright, then the solution is pretty straightforward, you should just change a couple of lines:
`browser.get('https://github.com/search')` and `elem = browser.find_element_by_name('q')`

Comment: @anonymouss, the reason why I use `find_elem_by_name` instead of `find_element_by_id` if simply because the search has no `id`, but has got a unique `name`. It's easy to figure out using browser developer tools, in Chrome it can be opened with `F12` key, or just right-click on the search bar and select `inspect`.  There's also a bunch of other element location methods, check out the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: @anonymouss, does this solve your problem? Also, make sure that you've got `chromedriver` configured right, you might want to provide a path to the executable explicitly, like that: `browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/to/chromedriver")`

Comment: Ohh, I really appreciate for your help. I used id instead of name. It is also great that you explained in details. Thanks again.